# Write a function that shows all the different combinations of n numbers in ascending ascending order

Tags: c

By logic it would have to go from 09, to 12, 13, 14, ..., 23,24, ..., 34, 35, ..., 79, 89.

However, I can't create the logic for the second decimal place to zero and get increasing. I cannot have 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88.

### The functions allowed are just writing, while I finish if other functions.

MY CODE:

```
void ft_putchar(char a)
{
    write(1, &a, 1);
}
void ft_print_combn(int n)
{
    int combn[n];
    int p;

    if (n <= 0 || n >= 10)
        return ;
    else
    {
        p = 0;
        while (p < n)
        {
            combn[p] = p;
            p++;
        }

        while (p > 0)
        {
            int maxdigit = 10;
            p = 0;
            while (p < n)
            {
                ft_putchar(combn[p] + '0');
                p++;
            }
            p = n;
            while (p--)
            {
                int digit = combn[p];

                if (digit < --maxdigit)
                {
                    combn[p++] = ++digit;
                    if (p <= n)
                    {
                        ft_putchar(',');
                        ft_putchar(' ');
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    ft_print_combn(2);
}
```

Comment: "I can't create the logic" is surely a problem, but how can we help?

Comment: I have to pass as a parameter the number of digits and according to that number create all possible combinations in increasing order. Starting from 01 to 89 because 98 is not possible because 8 is less than 9.

Comment: See SO question 68724538 -- which is a duplicate of this question and provides an answer.

Answer (score -2):

A corrected answer, based upon your comment follows.
This solution uses a two-character string to build the digits and print the values. This solution is written using Ada. You can translate the algorithm to C. You can also modify this algorithm to work with n digits, but n must not exceed 9 or you will not be able to meet your requirements.

```ada
   procedure print_digits is
      subtype digit_values is Character range '0' .. '9';
      subtype digit_sequence is String (1 .. 2);
      sequence : digit_sequence;
   begin
      for first_digit in
        digit_values'First .. digit_values'Pred (digit_values'Last)
      loop
         sequence (1) := first_digit;
         for second_digit in Character'Succ (first_digit) .. digit_values'Last
         loop
            sequence (2) := second_digit;
            Put_Line (sequence);
         end loop;
      end loop;
   end print_digits;
```

In Ada I start by creating a subtype of the type Character limited to the character representation of decimal digits ('0' through '9');

I then create a two-character string to build the increasing value sequences from left to right as you describe above.

The logic is accomplished in two nested for loops. The first for loop increments through the values '0' through '8'. The value '9' cannot be in the first string position because nothing can increment past 9 in this problem.

Each time through the outer loop the value of the first string element is assigned the new value of the variable first_digit.

The inner loop increments from the value succeeding the value of first_digit to '9'. Each iteration that value is assigned to the second element of the sequence array.

The sequence array is then output to standard output, one sequence per line.

The output of a program calling print_digits is:

```
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
34
35
36
37
38
39
45
46
47
48
49
56
57
58
59
67
68
69
78
79
89
```

Comment: but I can't print repeated or smaller numbers. In this case, I can't print the 10 for (1 > 0) or the 11 for (1 == 1) as well as the other possibilities must follow this rule.

Comment: "This solution is written using Ada. You can translate the algorithm to C." Is this because of your interpretation of [how to answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822)? Because that's **really** not how it's supposed to work. Instead, please vote to close questions which are unclear or unfocused. "Here's my code, I can't get it to work write, help please" is both of those. Please also read [answer] and keep in mind that this is **not a discussion forum**.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to help without doing the author's homework.